# What if I return None in django views and handle it in middleware?

Tags: python, django

We always return HttpResponse in Django views, but now I want to do this pack stuff in middleware.
That is, I can return a dict (or something else) or raise an error in view, and my middleware will detect it:
If it returns a dict (body), the middleware will pack dict like {error: None, code: 0, body: bodydict} and use JSON.dumps to get a string as response content (with code 0 for example); 
If it raise an error, the middleware will stringify the error and pack it like {error: "Some Error", code: 500, body: []}

If the view returns None, the middleware will pack as {error: None, code: 0, body: None}

But the problem is, django will detect the return of view. If it returns None, it will log an Error:

```
The view xxxView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Now I want to remove this log. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I **think** the only way you could do this(easily) is with a decorator, not middleware the get_response method or whatever that gets passed into the middleware pretty much wants something with at a minimum a callable `render` method, and without lots of work is pretty unavoidable

```
def jsonify(fn):
    def __inner(*args,**kwargs):
        result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
        return HTTPResponse(json.dumps({"data":result}))

@jsonify
def my_function(request,...):
    return None
```

Comment: actually this is my origin approach to handle all my requests; but i think middleware is a easier way - only need add one-line code after all

Comment: that obscures functionality ... django makes great strides to avoid permitting this ... you should use a different framework if you really want this.  Most lightweight rest frameworks support this (flask, falcon, molten, to name a few) there might be some base class in django-rest-framework that autowraps all methods of an APIView in something like this (maybe), so as long as you use django-rest-framework class based views maybe you can do this ...